# How to handle htaccess errors using php?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've used `ini_set('post_max_size',"2M")` in my php script to limit uploads file size. it didn't worked (do you know why ? )

So i put these rules on my `htaccess` file :

`php_value post_max_size 2M`

`php_value upload_max_filesize 2M`

So when i upload a file larger than 2M , my php script shows this error :

`Warning: POST Content-Length of 15903708 bytes exceeds the limit of 2097152 bytes in Unknown on line 0`

How can i handle this error in an appropriate way ? (something like try catch).

Note : I wouldn't like to hide this error.

Comment: what values you see when you use `phpinfo()` ?

Comment: what values do you want ?
upload_max_filesize 20M

Answer (score 1):

In your upload script, have you tried:

```
if ($_FILES['upfile']['size'] > 2000000) {
    $error_message ="Exceeded filesize limit.";
}
```

Also there is try/catch in php for example:

```
try{
  //your upload script
}
catch(Exception $e){
    $error_message = "File did not upload: ". $e->getMessage();
}
```

From this you should be able to handle any errors how you want

Another solution is a custom error handler:

```
 set_error_handler("warning_handler", E_WARNING);

 //your upload script

 function warning_handler($errno, $errstr) { 
 // do someing with your error here
 }


 restore_error_handler(); // reinstates original error handling
```

Comment: You can use this rule after file has been uploaded completely.

Comment: still getting that warning.

Comment: I don't know if this would work - however it may be worth a try... if you use @ before move_uploaded_file to surpress the warning,  the try/catch statement may still catch it.

Comment: Another solution maybe to create a custom error handler.... ill up date my answer shortly

Comment: thanks. i tried this before. not works.i think the errors that throws by htaccess can't be managed by php.